# Student Visa Czech Republic

Tags: visa, czech-republic

I’m leaving next week for my study abroad semester but the problem is that I still don’t have my student visa from the embassy of Czech Republic even though it’s after the processing time. The embassy officer has no clue why there’s a delay for my visa and tried to contact the ministry of interior in Prague but they haven’t received any replies back.

I was wondering if it’s a good idea to request the passport to be sent back to me and travel to Prague as a tourist for the beginning of my studies, and then send the passport back to the embassy once my visa has been finalized? I know I won’t be without a passport for a few weeks and I wouldn’t risk trying to travel to another country. I’ll use FEDEX international express both ways, with signature and a tracking number Would love to hear anyone’s suggestion. I just can’t afford to change my flight and pay $275 for the fee and without a set date on when the visa is going to be ready.

Comment: You may be able to cancel your flight reservation now and apply the fare, less the change fee, in the future, to a new ticket.

Comment: What does your school say?

Answer (score 1):

It is [perfectly legal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25537/is-it-legal-to-study-while-on-a-tourist-schengen-visa) to study while on a short-term Schengen visa, so there's nothing wrong with your plan. However you need to double check with your local Czech consulate if they would allow you to mail the passport to them rather than appearing in person to stamp the visa sticker. Otherwise you might need to fly back to your home country just to visit the consulate.